# fatal exception,not found resource id

Tags: android, string, debugging, exception, resources

I have encountered a fatal error and an error in my string resource on my activity.
This my string code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="app_name">Favorites</string>
<string name="action_settings">تنظیمات</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="title_activity_favorites">لیست علاقه مندی ها</string>
<string name="favorites">لیست علاقه مندی ها</string>
<string name="title_activity_show__subjects">نمایش  مبحث ها</string>
<string name="favorites_added">به لیست علاقه مندی ها افزوده شد</string>
<string name="favorites_removed">از لیست علاقه مندی ها حذف شد</string>
<string name="subject_1">شروع</string>
<string name="subject_2">آموزش عملی</string>
<string name="subject_3">وسایل مورد نیاز</string>
<string name="subject_4">تنظیمات</string>
<string name="subject_5">خروج</string>
<string name="subject_text_1">متن مربوط به آموزش اول</string>
<string name="subject_text_2">متن مربوط به آموزش دوم</string>
<string name="subject_text_3">متن مربوط به آموزش سوم</string>
<string name="subject_text_4">متن مربوط به آموزش چهارم</string>
<string name="subject_text_5">متن مربوط به آموزش پنجم</string>
<string name="alo_text_1">مقاومت</string>
<string name="alo_text_2">سلف</string>
<string name="alo_text_3">خازن</string>
<string name="alo_text_4">آمپرسنج</string>
<string name="alo_text_5">مدولاسیون</string>
<string name="alo_text_6">کلمات اختصاری در موبایل</string>
<string name="alo_text_7">فیلتر</string>
<string name="alo_text_8">بخش های اصلی گوشی</string>
<string name="alo_text_9">صفحه بعدی</string>
<string name="alo_text_10">ترانزیستور</string>
<string name="alo_text_11">دیود</string>
<string name="alo_text_12">کریستال</string>
<string name="alo_text_13">بخش تغذیه</string>
<string name="alo_text_14">بخش شارژ</string>
<string name="alo_text_15">بخش دیجیتال</string>
<string name="alo_text_16">بخش کنترل</string>
<string name="alo_text_17">واسط های کاربری</string>
<string name="alo_text_18">آی سی درایور</string>
<string name="alo_text_19">ال سی دی</string>
<string name="alo_text_20">بخش مخابرات</string>
<string name="alo_text_21">بخش RF</string>
<string name="alo_text_22">بخش صوتی</string>
<string name="alo_text_23">خطوط pcm</string>
<string name="alo_text_24">آی سی ها</string>
<string name="alo_text_25">شابلون زدن</string>
<string name="alo_text_26">فلش کردن</string>
<string name="alo_1">مقاومت</string>
<string name="alo_2">سلف</string>
<string name="alo_3">خازن</string>
<string name="alo_4">آمپرسنج</string>
<string name="alo_5">مدولاسیون</string>
<string name="alo_6">کلمات اختصاری در موبایل</string>
<string name="alo_7">فیلتر</string>
<string name="alo_8">بخش های اصلی گوشی</string>
<string name="alo_9">صفحه بعدی</string>
<string name="alo_10">ترانزیستور</string>
<string name="alo_11">دیود</string>
<string name="alo_12">کریستال</string>
<string name="alo_13">بخش تغذیه</string>
<string name="alo_14">بخش شارژ</string>
<string name="alo_15">بخش دیجیتال</string>
<string name="alo_16">بخش کنترل</string>
<string name="alo_17">واسط های کاربری</string>
<string name="alo_18">آی سی درایور</string>
<string name="alo_19">ال سی دی</string>
<string name="alo_20">بخش مخابرات</string>
<string name="alo_21">بخش RF</string>
<string name="alo_22">بخش صوتی</string>
<string name="alo_23">خطوط pcm</string>
<string name="alo_24">آی سی ها</string>
<string name="alo_25">شابلون زدن</string>
<string name="alo_26">فلش کردن</string>
```

This is my activity that used alo_number strings:

```
package vangah.dregooshitsho;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Show_Subject2 extends Activity {

public String alo_number;
public SharedPreferences shared;
public SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
Globals2 global = new Globals2();
public ImageView iv_favorites;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.show_subjects);

iv_favorites = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null)
        alo_number = extras.getString("alo_number");

    TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    String stringName_1 = "alo_" + String.valueOf(alo_number);;
    int resID_1 = getResources().getIdentifier(stringName_1, "string", getPackageName());
    tv1.setText(resID_1);



    // Favorites
    shared = getSharedPreferences("Prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = shared.edit();

    final int subject2_number_int = Integer.parseInt(alo_number);
    final String this_subject2 = "alo_" + String.valueOf(subject2_number_int);

    final Boolean b1 = shared.getBoolean(this_subject2, false);
    if (b1){
        iv_favorites.setImageResource(R.drawable.favorite_selected);
    }else{
        iv_favorites.setImageResource(R.drawable.favorite_not_selected);
    }

    iv_favorites.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Boolean b2 = shared.getBoolean(this_subject2, false);
            if (b2){
                editor.putBoolean(this_subject2, false);
                editor.apply();
                iv_favorites.setImageResource(R.drawable.favorite_not_selected);
                // show message
                String message = getResources().getString(R.string.favorites_removed);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                editor.putBoolean(this_subject2, true);
                editor.apply();
                iv_favorites.setImageResource(R.drawable.favorite_selected);
                // show message
                String message = getResources().getString(R.string.favorites_added);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}


@Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.itemFavorites:
        startActivity(new Intent(Show_Subject2.this, Favorites.class));
        return true;
    case R.id.action_setting:
        startActivity(new Intent(Show_Subject2.this, SettingActivity.class));
        return true;
    default: 
        return true;
    }   
}

}
```

and my debuggable shows me the error is in this line:

```
alo_number = extras.getString("alo_number");
```

How can I mitigate this error?

Comment: where did you fill up the intent?

Comment: alo_number = extras.getString("alo_number"); , this line is trying to retrieve a value from the Bundle with the key "alo_number" , are you passing something into the bundle from your previous activity with this key?

Comment: sorry my english language is not good.no im not use this key in any activity except FAvorite activity and Prefs activity.

Comment: blackbelt in main activity i have a list view and onitemlitener when is the position==0 ,that fill the intent and showed this activity,but when i click on first item in list view i had that error,not found resource in show_subject2